# ubi-partman failed with exit code 10 - ubuntu 18.04

Tags: system-installation, 18.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop. After choosing the partitionn i have the following error message: `grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install into / target/.`

[image]

Then I tried to install via "try ubuntu" and i get:

```
ubi-partman failed with exit code 10
```

### [image]

What should I do?

Comment: what does /var/log/syslog file say near the end?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do the following (for beginners):

I assume you already have a flash usb with ubuntu .iso

1. Boot your usb on try ubuntu
2. Ubuntu Software [image] > install Gparted [image]
3. Open gparted, right click on you desired partition to install Ubuntu > new >  New Size : 200 MiB; filw system: fat32; > Add ; Something like this should be done:
   [image]
4. Right click on EFI partition just created, Manage flags > boot
5. Apply changes on gparted then exit gparted
6. Install Ubuntu, when appears where to install choose *something else*>
7. double click on efi partition, choose EFI
8. Double click on desired partition to install ubuntu, choose ext4, mount point "/"
9. Install

Comment: Hi @Vitor I tried to do this (I am installing Ububnti 20.04) and it still gives the same error whe I try to install - does not get to the place where I can choose "something else"

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

1. Create FAT32 partition with 200Mib with "boot" flag
2. Run installation
3. Choose partition to install ubuntu...
4. Choose FAT32 partition as EFI partition
5. Choose your swap partition if you want
6. Install

Comment: This isn't at all clear.  I presume I have an EFI partition and a ext4 (or whatever) / partition and I install to that partition.  Do I need to format the efi partition as well as /?  Where do I set grub to be installed?

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused by using a 1TB drive for installation, I tried again with a 16GB thumb drive and it worked fine.