# ubi-partman failed with exit code 10 -installing Lubuntu 18.04 using dd image

Tags: lubuntu, dd

Trying to install Lubuntu 18.04 onto a laptop using a dd image (meaning I don't have to create a partition). When the installation was about 3/4 of the way done, I got the following message:
**ubi-partman failed with exit code 10. Further information may be found in /var/log/sys/log. Do you want to try running this step again before continuing? If you do not, your installation may fail entirely or may be broken.**

I should mention that installing using an ISO image is not an option for me at the moment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ubi-partman failed with exit code 10 - ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032905/ubi-partman-failed-with-exit-code-10-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: So are you trying to have the *live* session run from disk?  ie. if I `dd` from an ISO to disk (which I've done before), the disk image will act like a thumb-drive making it suitable for installation on another drive?

Comment: yes, I am trying to do that @guiverc

Comment: I would like to add an update, I was going to restart the installation process when I got a message that said **"This computer has Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on it, What would you like to do?"** I find this odd because when I shut off and turn on the laptop, no OS appears to be there. Also, the dd image I have is clearly for installing Lubuntu, not Ubuntu.

Comment: The Lubuntu / Ubuntu makes no difference. The base system of Lubuntu is Ubuntu, so it's expected that it is recognized as Ubuntu by any tool that explores the base system (not desktop or user files). Grub for example usually detects all *flavors* as Ubuntu; as that's what boots the system (the GUI & desktop are started much later and those are the *flavor*).  Did you verify your ISO image? and write to disk? (ie. prior to install?) https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck

Comment: Details of your hardware may help.

Comment: @guiverc it is a dd image, and yes, I made sure to verify it before attempting to install.

Comment: `dd` is a tool/command; I use it to write my ISOs to thumb-drive; so telling me it's a `dd` image doesn't actually tell me much; it's been a command for unix systems since the unix v5 or mid-1980s or before Linux was created (even longer for those of us who used ibm mainframes)

Comment: Oh, well I obtained the DD image using Rufus. (There was an option to either have an ISO or DD, I chosed DD because I was having trouble with finding a partition to install on)

Comment: I just experienced this issue doing a QA-test install using a Ubuntu-MATE *focal* daily.. in my case it was because I made a mistake & thus BACK I believe...  You hadn't used the BACK button during install because of an error had you?  (I don't have time to explore it currently, i intend to return & explore later)

Comment: From what I can see, the issue occurs when there is a uEFI versus BIOS(legacy) boot mode config issue....   I gather I created this with my 'BACK' in prior comment (ie. box is in BIOS, but my use of BACK caused setting of new install to be different to what I had selected (in error) before..  I'd suggest rebooting box & starting again  (worked for my intended QA-test install).